# SpriteKit Detect Press and Hold on Label

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am trying to make an app where the user can press a button to increase the level of some skill.  However, I am using the "touchesBegan" method, and if the user wants to upgrade the skill by 25 points, the user will have to click the label 25 times.  Here is my code currently to detect if the user has touched the sprite.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
  SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
  if([node.name isEqualTo:@"red-upgrade"]){
    if(_xp >= pow(_rpower+1, 2)){
        _rpower ++;
        _xp -= pow(_rpower, 2);
    }
    _rpowerlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Red Power: %i", _rpower];
  }
}
```

Is there a way to implement a hold and press gesture on a sprite or a label? So the user can just press and hold on the upgrade button and it will increment many times instead of continuously clicking?

Any and all suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a member referencing the skill button in the enclosing class and then and start an action on the button to increment the needed value in the touch begin method:

```
  if([node.name isEqualTo:@"red-upgrade"]){
            [self.skillButton runAction:[SKAction repeatForever:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:0.5],
                                                                                 [SKAction runBlock:^{
                if(self.xp >= pow(self.rpower+1, 2)){
                    self.rpower ++;
                    self.xp -= pow(self.rpower, 2);
                }
                self.rpowerlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Red Power: %i", self.rpower]
            }]]]]];
  }
```

I used a small delay or else the value will be increased really fast (unless that what you want).

In the `touchEnd` method stop the node's action with `[self.skillButton removeAllActions];` regardless where the location is (since then the user can slide his finger and the location will be different)

Not sure if the cleanest of solutions but that should work for you